# Avoid instantiating new objects inside loops in java

Tags: java, loops, pmd

I would like to avoid crating the new instance of `SelectItem` in side the loop.
Could you please help me how can i avoid it.

```
public List<SelectItem> createLocales() {
    final List<SelectItem> enabledLocales = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
    final List<String> langCodes = labeldbservice.getEnabledLocales();
    LOGGER.debug("getEnabledLocales: size={0}", langCodes);
    for (final String langCode : langCodes) {
        enabledLocales.add(new SelectItem(langCode, LocaleUtils.toLocale(langCode).getDisplayName()));
    }
    return enabledLocales;
}
```

Comment: Why would you like to avoid it? This seems to be the cleanest way to add a `SelectItem` to `enabledLocales` for each `langCode`.

Comment: Then how would u create different objects for different langCode?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PMD: Avoid instantiating new objects inside loops](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17340421/pmd-avoid-instantiating-new-objects-inside-loops)

Answer (score 1):

```
public List<SelectItem> createLocales() {
    final List<SelectItem> enabledLocales = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
    final List<String> langCodes = labeldbservice.getEnabledLocales();
    final SelectItem sItem = new SelectItem();

    LOGGER.debug("getEnabledLocales: size={0}", langCodes);
    for (final String langCode : langCodes) {
        sItem.setValue(langCode);
        sItem.setLabel(LocaleUtils.toLocale(langCode).getDisplayName());
        enabledLocales.add(sItem);
    }
    return enabledLocales;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this PMD Issue by creating a method which will return a new object. I will call this method in loop to get new object.
For your code it would be something like this.

```
public List<SelectItem> createLocales() {
    final List<SelectItem> enabledLocales = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
    final List<String> langCodes = labeldbservice.getEnabledLocales();
    LOGGER.debug("getEnabledLocales: size={0}", langCodes);
    for (final String langCode : langCodes) {
        enabledLocales.add(getNewSelectItem(langCode, LocaleUtils.toLocale(langCode).getDisplayName()));
    }
    return enabledLocales;
}

public SelectItem getNewSelectItem(String langCode, String displayName) {
    return new SelectItem(langCode, displayName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not see why you want to change this code but assuming that you have measured this to be a performance bottleneck, either cache the result of createLocales (globally or per Thread using a ThreadLocal that lazily builds it up) or perhaps instead of returning a list, return a map from langCode to values that lazily instantiate and cache the required SelectItem instances.

Comment: initially i had used map only but for retrieval operation at UI side is slow with ma so i am trying to using list interface