# ArrayList - Is it better to clear a List or Reinitialize it?

Tags: java, list, arraylist

Which is the best practice between

- `ArrayList.clear();`
- `new ArrayList<Object>();`

I have a list which gets data, I use them and then I have to recycle it.
Which is the best way?

Comment: Check this out : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18370780/empty-an-arraylist-or-just-create-a-new-one-and-let-the-old-one-be-garbage-colle

Comment: First one, as you're reusing the same object. But calling new operator will create a new object.

Comment: Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11740055/829571

Answer (score 2):

I think if u just clear it its 1 less object for GC to handle, so its better.

I dont see any actual advantage on creating a new array list object if not changing the type.

Comment: GC of short-lived objects is not very expensive.